# How to verify if a sequence of nodes will form a red black tree

Tags: java, red-black-tree

I am getting a sequence of nodes from the user and I am supposed to write a function that will check these nodes and return a boolean output to the user explaining whether it's a red-black tree or not.

The input will be in this format:

For example: 5B1 2B2 9B3 1R4 3R5 8R6 10R7

Where the leftmost number in each node is the value of the node and the character is the colour of the node and the rightmost number is the position of the node in the tree.

The positions are considered as following:

```
                1
              /  \
             2    3
            / \  / \
           4  5  6  7
```

etc...

Following the example given that means that the first node in the input 5B1 basically means that 5 is the value and black is the colour and 1 is the position which is basically the root.

The red black tree driven from the example input is :

```
                      5(b)
                    /     \
                   /       \
                 2(b)       9(b)
                /  \       /  \
               /    \     /    \
           1(r)     3(r) 8(r)  10(r)
```

How can I write a function that will process such an input and check whether it is a red black tree or not.

Please note that the input doesn't need to have the positions in order, so a different variation of the example input given could be: 2B2 5B1 9B3 1R4 10R7 8R6 3R5
and it should still return the same answer.

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: There is no such thing as "nodes that will form a red black tree". There is a binary tree implementation called a "red black" tree, but nodes are just nodes. Did you mean a "balanced" tree?

Comment: @Bohemian I don't think you understood what I meant, the user will input the nodes that are in a red black tree. My job is to have a function that will verify if it's a valid red-black tree or not. So by checking the input from the user and checking where each node's position is, it's colour and it's value and making sure it doesn't violate the properties of the red-black tree

Comment: Obviously, @Bohemian, the OP is asking how to verify if the node description provided represents a valid RB tree, i.e., the root is black, there is no red node with a red parent, and the black height of every path from a node to leaf is the same. So in this context, there is so such a thing as "nodes that will form a red black tree". Obviously.

Comment: @LewBloch Exactly. I would just like a rough idea on how to code a function that would verify those three properties based on that kind of input.

Comment: First, figure out a structure that would represent the tree described by your input. It should be obvious that manipulating strings will be frustrating and error-prone. Once you have parsed the input into a program structure representing the described tree, run analysis over that structure to see if it conforms to the rules. Your structure representing the tree will need objects representing the nodes and/or the edges of the tree, including how they connect and their colors. From that you can determine if it's a binary tree, black height of each node, etc.